# Listen on a View if the View change its XY position

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I listen on a View to obtain its XY coordination if it is moving or its XY position change? The View is not necessary to be dragged (or by user touch event), it may change if the orientation change or pushed (upward) by the showing keyboard or etc. I want to know its updated XY coordination when it changes, how can I do that?

Comment: You probably can use [onPreDrawListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener.html) or [onGlobalLayoutListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html) to listen to the position change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may do something like this

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        findViewById(R.id.textView).getX();
                        findViewById(R.id.textView).getY();

                    }
                });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's a good solution except you should not ever call findViewById inside onGlobalLayout  (or any other method that gets called many times!) since it's expensive operation and you only need to do it once!

Comment: If getting the target view instance, `addOnLayoutChangeListener` should be better than `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` because `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` will be called due to the change of all child of the root view.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `addOnLayoutChangeListener` should work. It is called when in layout function of the view it find out the frame bounds changes. If the frame bounds doesn't change so basically if the parent bounds change instead and that changes view location, we probably dont get this event here and then some addOnGlobalLayoutListener with som additional code that will compare real location on screen will be necessary but I would not go that way, because it attracts additional issues.