# How to listen for multiple GlobalLayout events

Tags: java, android, listener

I am trying to listen for `GlobalLayout`  using

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    int c=0;
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        c++; //without removing the listener c will grow for ever even though there is no GlobalLayout events
        view.setText(""+c);
    }
});
```

but it's called endlessly.

---

I know I should remove the listener like this: `view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);`

But I want to keep the listener alive for the next `GlobalLayout` events.

Currently I am just trying to listen for view position changing using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461784/listen-on-a-view-if-the-view-change-its-xy-position)
I tried `onPreDraw` but it is the same.

---

### Is it possible to listen for several `GlobalLayout` events?

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `OnLayoutChangeListener`?

Comment: @PavelPoley The exact same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65831475/how-to-listen-for-several-layoutchange-calls

Comment: @ATP Why don't you `increment c` only if the position has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted as an example shouldn't compile because of issues with accessing the variable `c` from the listener. If you try it, you should get the following error in Android Studio:

> Variable 'c' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final or effectively final

We can take the suggestion that error check suggests and create a one-element array as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final int[] c = {0};
        final View[] view = {findViewById(R.id.textView)};
        view[0].getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                c[0]++;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you run this code against the following layout, you will see that the listener is called twice which I think corresponds to two layout passes:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If the layout is somehow modified within the global layout listener, then it will trigger another layout and another call to the the listener. If the listener again makes a change, the listener will be called yet again and so on forever.

It would be helpful if you would post the actual code you are having trouble with or a simple project that demonstrates the problem. Is the layout somehow modified within the listener?

---

**Update:** As you say in one of your comments on this answer, your issue was that you made a change to a view in the global layout listener which triggered another layout and another call to the listener ad infinitum. Once you removed the code that made the layout change, that particular issue was resolved.

Comment: Thank you so much,I didn't think about those type of problems `"If the layout is somehow modified within the global layout listener, then it will trigger another layout and another call to the the listener. If the listener again makes a change, the listener will be called yet again and so on forever."` Although that I moved the view, it's not what caused the problem ,as you said the code I first provided wasn't the code that made the problem, my real code used `view.setText(c+"")` (to see c value), and this is what probably made the problem because it changed the UI and launched another event.

Comment: I changed the code to a code that has the problem. Thank you for bringing this to my attention, please update your answer to get the bounty

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to trigger the code once the view position has changed, then you could probably just check if the x, y coordinates has changed before increasing the variable `c`

Something like this:

```
int c = 0;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int x2 = view.getX();
        int y2 = view.getY();
        // do not increase c unless position has changed
        if (x2 != x && y2 != y) {
            c++;
            // update coordinates values
            x = x2;
            y = y2;
        }
        
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes I thought about it... but it's really not efficient. is there other way to do that? Thanks for the answer

Comment: How is position of the view changing? is it an animation?

Comment: constraint layout, when a  constrained view increase his size.

Comment: Can't you know when the size will change? then register a pre draw listener at that time?

Comment: `preDraw` has the same problem

Comment: Could you please explain more on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227788/discussion-between-khaled-and-atp).

Answer (score 0):

you can set the Listener on your Viewes try to use `view.addOnLayoutChangeListener`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener

it will give you the old and new X&Y of your layout and you can adjust your view base on it

Comment: The same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65831475/how-to-listen-for-several-layoutchange-calls

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a flag to detect if it is a normal event or a `setText()` that is called by the listener and skip it if needed.

Code not tested. But I guess you will get the idea.

```
int c=0;

view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new CustomLayoutListener() {

     int c=0;

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

    if(skipEvent)
            return;

    c++;

    //flag skipEvent while performing setText()
    skipEvent = true;
        view.setText(""+c);
    skipEvent = false;

    }
});


class CustomLayoutListener extends ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    static boolean skipEvent;

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {}
}
```

Comment: This won't work, because `setText` doesn't do a layout synchronously, it just sets a flag which will cause a layout to happen on the next frame.